# How to get text from a TextFile and putting it to a Table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, bufferedreader, filewriter

I am trying to put text from a text file to a table I want it to display on the table when pressing a button. It does not display any errors it just does not work. Can someone please explain why and how to make it work. The text is divided with ;

```
       private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
        {                                         
        try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
         FileReader("zam.txt"));
        String r;
        int v =0;

        do{
            r = br.readLine();
            if(r!=null){
                 v++;
            }
        }while(r!=null);

        Object[] row = new String[v];

        do{
            r = br.readLine();
            if(r!=null){
                for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {

                    int ix = r.indexOf(";");
                    row[i] = r.substring(0, ix);
                    r = r.substring(ix+1);

                    int zn = r.indexOf(";");
                    row[i] += r.substring(0, zn);
                    r = r.substring(zn+1);

                    int xn = r.indexOf(";");
                    row[i] += r.substring(0, xn);
                    r = r.substring(xn+1);

                    int an = r.indexOf(";");
                    row[i] += r.substring(0, an);

                    table.addRow(row);
                }
            }
        }while(r!=null);

        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you tried?  Have you tried printing out `r`?  It looks like you count the number of lines, but never reset the `BufferedReader`

Comment: I printed r and it is null.

Comment: *I printed r and it is null* - I guess it never goes into your `if` so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should shorten this.

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
    try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
     FileReader("zam.txt"));

    String r;
    do{
        r = br.readLine();
        if(r!=null){
            String [] sline=r.split(";");
            table.addRow(sline);                
        }
    }while(r!=null);

    br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Reason: you read the file 2 times but without resetting the stream. Why?

Then you counted the number of lines and took this number as number of columns, why?

Answer (score 0):

You count the number of lines in the file

```
do{
    r = br.readLine();
    if(r!=null){
        v++;
    }
}while(r!=null);
```

After that you try to read from the file, after the EOF has already been reached

```
do{
    r = br.readLine();
    if(r!=null){
        [...]
    }
}while(r!=null);
```

`r = br.readLine();` will return `null`, since the EOF has been reached, and skip over the loop

---

To fix this, you can either reopen the file

```
//counting code
br.close();
br = new BufferedReader([...]);
//reading code
```

Or you can add the lines to a `List` instead, and use that

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader([...]);
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine())
    lines.add(line);
String[] row = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
```

---

If you're just adding the values to a table, it may be easier to not store the file at all

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader([...]);
for(String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine())
    table.addRow(line.split(";"));
```

Comment: Thank you.
Now I must figure out how to put the words into Table properly.

Comment: Got it Thank you.